# Recursive namespaces not working properly with type providers static parameters

Tags: f#, type-providers

From [#5227](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5227)

Using the following tools

> *Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview Version 15.8.0 Preview 2.0 VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.8.0-pre.2.0+27729.1 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02558 on Windows 10*

**Repro steps**

- Create a library project
- Change the Target .NET Framework version to 4.5.2
- Change Target F# version to 4.1 (Core 4.4.3.0)
- Install SQLProvider package from NuGet
- Replace Library1.fs content with the following code
  ;

> ```
> namespace Ns1
> #nowarn "40"
>
> open FSharp.Data.Sql
>
> [<AutoOpen>]
> module Definitions =
>     let [<Literal>] connString = @"Valid connection string"
>     let t1 = T1() //T1 not defined
>
> type T1() = 
>     static member f1() = connString
>
> type amplaSQL = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString = connString>
> ```

As expected 'let t1 = T1()' gives an error, being the type T1 defined later in the file. 
This is what rec namespace should allow

- Change the first line to 'namespace rec Ns1'

**Expected behaviour**

No errors

**Actual behavior**

As expected, the previous error goes away as T1 is now known even in the affected line. However, a new unexpected error comes up in the last code line, complaining that connString is not defined

> ```
> namespace rec Ns1
> #nowarn "40"
>
> open FSharp.Data.Sql
>
> [<AutoOpen>]
> module Definitions =
>     let [<Literal>] connString = @"Valid connection string"
>     let t1 = T1()
>
> type T1() = 
>     static member f1() = connString
>
> type amplaSQL = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString = connString> //connString not defined
> ```

**Question**: is this behaviour expected (am I not using the rec namespace correctly?) or is it an issue of the F# compiler?

Comment: This would be better to report to https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is less of a question and more of a bug report. Comment mentions where to better report the issue.

Comment: @ReedCopsey  I am not sure that this is a bug, could be something I don't know (or didn't find in the docs); moreover, I did the effort to report it here as I think this could be useful for stackoverflow readers as well (it would have been easier to only report the issue in github). Moreover, even if I found the issue working in Visual Studio, it looks more like a F# compiler issue than a Visual F# tools issue, hence I chose the fsharp and not visualfsharp github repo to report the issue. Ill edit the post to add a question though

Comment: Where do you see that last error? (connString not defined) Do you see it in the output from the compiler in the Output pane? Do you see it in the Error List pane? If so, do you still see it when you select "Build Only" from the dropdown in that pane? Does it say "successful" at the bottom of VS?

Comment: @BentTranberg Do you see it in the output from the compiler in the Output pane? YES. Do you see it in the Error List pane? YES. If so, do you still see it when you select "Build Only" from the dropdown in that pane?YES. Does it say "successful" at the bottom of VS? NO it says Build failed

Comment: Not an issue related to intellisense then.